# How to connect flutterflow to a django api via custom actions?

Tags: dart, flutter-dependencies, flutterflow

Pretty much as the title says im trying to write a custom action to connect to my django api. Its stored in a AWS EC2 instance but I have a url for it. Cant seem to find anyone who has done this yet.

I know that you can make custom actions that support CRUD operations with databases that arent firebase/supabase but i dont see anything on how you can do that with django.